# Can I override loginwindow on Tiger?

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, sfauthorizationpluginview

My software authorizes the user prior to booting Mac OS X (Tiger and Leopard.)  I want to use SFAuthorizationPluginView to create a plugin to attempt to use our pre-boot authorization (cached securely) for user login to Mac OS X for single-sign-on capability.  I have not yet validated if that will even work for Leopard, but am assuming I will be able to do it.  (Dangerous, I know.)

**The question is how can I do this for Tiger and will that solution work for Leopard?**

I continue to research, if I find a solution I will share.

Comment: I just asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065759/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-mac-login-screen), and found yours when looking up sfauthorizationpluginview.  What have you learned in the last seven months about this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been working on this much at all until now. We dropped support for Tiger so I don't need an answer to this question so much. You might try Apple's CDSA mailing list. I read your question and don't have an answer for that either.  Yet.  I'll have one soon though. I need it.  :-)

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear that last bit.  We dropped support of Tiger last year and have now re-instated it.  (Sigh)

Comment: I misstated what I need.  I need this for Leopard.  We will not be adding Tiger support unless our biggest customer demands it.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd expect to do is to change the /etc/authorization database to accept your authorization as sufficient, but the comments around system.login.console don't lead me to expect that would work. You could circumvent LoginWindow by providing your own login-like app which you bring up with launchd instead of com.apple.loginwindow, but that seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: I am not sure I want to override loginwindow.app that much. Besides, we are not adding NEW credentials to Mac OS X, just passing those used in our pre-boot authentication into Mac OS X so the user need not login twice to the same computer if they match.

Comment: definitely sounds like you want to change the login requirement in /etc/authorization to be a k-of-n thing, then