# OS X lock screen with pure C?

Tags: c, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I know this is possible, because I have a binary I wrote a couple years ago to do exactly this. Unfortunately, I didn't save the source code.

I know that it was written in pure C, and I called against an OS X API and was able to lock the screen. Googling for "pure C OS X lock screen" and similar strings isn't getting me much; I saw documentation on how to do it in Objective C but that's not what I'm looking for.

Anyone have any idea how I accomplished this previously?

Comment: Are you sure you used an API and not a `system()` call?

Comment: Some bizarre thoughts: maybe you could disassemble your old binary or investigate system calls using [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `CGSCreateLoginSession()` -- it's a private function and not documented by Apple. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065759/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-mac-login-screen) for an example of its use.

Comment: Please consider providing at least some example. Google is not considered an answer here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is by using a call to `system()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  system("/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend");
  return 0;
}
```