# Display app on Mac login screen?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, authentication

Is it possible to launch and display an app on the Mac login screen? Or add controls to it?

Let's say I want to build a simple mac app that gives the user 3 buttons before logging in. Each button just does some small background thing.

My end goal is to have some way for the user to execute some 'maintenance' tasks without logging in.

Comment: Have a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065759/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-mac-login-screen

Comment: Look at the questions with tag [sfauthorizationpluginview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfauthorizationpluginview)